# handle bar complie issues

Tags: handlebars.js

uncaught exception: Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 1.0.0) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (<= 1.0.rc.2).

I am running handlebar with node and getting this error. not sure whats happing.

Answer (score 0):

Your precompiler needs to be updated to a version greater than or equal to 1.0.0.  You could alternatively downgrade your runtime to 1.0.rc.2 or less.